# mmap dies with cannot open /dev/mem after several accesses

Tags: c++, c, embedded, embedded-linux

I am writing some user-space drivers using mmap on a dual core ARM A9 to access some HW registers inside an FPGA. We have a custom SPI block that talks to another chip which we access HW registers inside that chip. I wrote a C++ class for my SPI "Driver" to basically break down reads/writes from/to addresses inside the external chip. I use mmap to access the SPI that is inside the FPGA (only occupies about 100bytes of memory space (0xFF20_2000 -> 0xFF20_007F)).

When I call the SPI class (and I only do this once for the driver) it goes through and performs a mmap open for the base address of the SPI HW.

```
void spi_op::cfg_mmap(){

    if( ( this->fd = open( "/dev/mem", ( O_RDWR | O_SYNC ) ) ) == -1 ) {
        printf( "ERROR: could not open \"/dev/mem\"...\n" );
        this->error = 1;
        return;
    }

    uint32_t map_addr_base = this->addr_base & MMAP_BASE_MASK;

    this->virtual_base = mmap( NULL, MMAP_PAGE_SIZE, ( PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE ), MAP_SHARED, this->fd, map_addr_base );

    if( this->virtual_base == MAP_FAILED ) {
        printf( "ERROR: mmap() failed...\n" );
        close( this->fd );
        this->error = 1;
        return;
    }

    //To initialize to the proper pointer in the event not on a page boundary
    this->virtual_base += (SPI_MASTER_ADDR_BASE - map_addr_base);
}
```

I have the SPI HW registers built as a struct/union for easy(ier) bit manipulations (I've X'd out things that could be considered proprietary, but are irrelevant for the question).

```
union spi_regs_reg1 {
    struct {
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 32;
    } bits;
    volatile uint32_t word;
};

union spi_regs_reg2 {
    struct {
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
        volatile uint32_t xxxx: 1;
    } bits;
    volatile uint32_t word;
};

struct spi_regs_regs {
    union spi_regs_blockid spi_regs_reg1;
    union spi_regs_gnrlsta spi_regs_reg2;
    blah blah blah
```

As part of the init/constructor I have a spi_regs struct pointer that gets assigned

```
void spi_op::spi_master_init(){

    this->cfg_mmap();

    spi_regs = (struct spi_regs_regs *)(this->virtual_base);


    //an Example of how I can now access the bits in the HW registers
    //Assert the RESET
    spi_regs->spi_regs_reg.bits.spi_reset = 1;
```

Whenever I want to do a read or write, I now simply call spi.read(addr) or spi.write(addr, data) to perform the operation.

This seems to work just fine, but occasionally after a bunch of read/writes I begin to get errors

```
"ERROR: could not open "/dev/mem"...".
```

Now this is something that is in the cfg_mmap() task. However I only call this once as part of the constructor. In this particular test I am setting up multiple different settings and running through each of them and resetting the external part inbetween (but not the SPI that I'm controlling with the mmap). I essentially have a for loop but the constructor of the SPI class is PRIOR to the for loop.

As a quick test while I was typing this, I change the error message in my cfg_mmap task to

```
"ERROR: blah could not open "/dev/mem"..."
```

then during the run I get this

```
<normal prints from my code>
ERROR: could not open "/dev/mem"...
ERROR: could not open "/dev/mem"...
ERROR: could not open "/dev/mem"...
ERROR: could not open "/dev/mem"...
ERROR: could not open "/dev/mem"...
ERROR: blah could not open "/dev/mem"...
Segmentation fault
root@arria10:~#
```

Is it possible that /dev/mem is getting overloaded or something like that? I've done some scouring in my code, I can't for the life of me find where I'm calling the SPI class more than once (the program isn't that complicated).

Comment: Well what is the specific error? (Hint: use `strerror(errno)` or `perror`)

Comment: using /dev/mem is not the best concept in case of security. /dev/mem may only allowed for root user. So you have to change the permissions. This is bad...

Comment: @lkj I would agree, however this is for validating HW and will not be used in production code. Eventually a real SW guy (not my HW self) will convert this to something more standard.

Comment: @immibis I will try this out. I will need to read some into how to use it.

Comment: The error I got was "Too many open files". I tried to change a few things in my code. I was making a SPI class in other classes that use the SPI, but I was only passing a pointer to the main SPI class. I'm still not entirely sure what is going on, but setting `ulimit -n <num>` allowed me to at least work around this for now. It's not a permanent solution, but for this particular test, I can live with this.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: It's likely that you're forgetting to close the file descriptors, thereby running out of fds for your process.  Either work with a smaller number of open files, or split your process into a number of cooperating processes that each handle a subset of the files you're opening.

Comment: @lSteveol How about finding out why you're opening too many files and fixing that? (On Linux you can `ls -l /proc/PID/fd` replacing PID with the actual process ID, and that will show you what files the process has open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that you class is called "spi_op" you may need to create spi_op::~spi_op() (so called "destructor") with a "munmap(virtual_base,MMAP_PAGE_SIZE)" and "close(fd)" instruction. So it may be a topic of destructor : see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm for example. If you proper use munmap() and close() you should not run into this problem anymore.

Comment: I'm accepting this, even though it _techincaly_ wasn't my issue. I did in fact have the destructor call the munmap function (even though it wasn't being needed). There was another class that was using something similar but wasn't using my SPI class. During some additional debug I found where I had another class calling mmap, but not unmapping. This was eventually seen as the issue. Most of my debug prints however seemed to happen during a SPI operation which led me to believe it to be the culprit. Thanks for the assistance